# How to fetch specific columns from multiple tables in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 tables,

1. Country:
   id,
   name
2. Province:
   id,
   name,
   country_id
3. City:
   id,
   name,
   province_id

I have defined relationships in Model as follows,

Country Model:

```
    public function Provinces()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Province');
        }
```

Province Model:

```
        public function Country()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
        }

        public function Cities()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\City');
        }
```

City Model:

```
    public function Province()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Province');
        }
```

I am using the below query, but it overwrites all the data with Country name.

```
    $city = DB::table('cities')
        ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
        ->join('countries', 'provinces.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
        ->select('cities.name','provinces.name','countries.name')
        ->get();
```

I want to fetch a result of only City Name, Province Name, Country Name from these tables in laravel 5. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: That is totally a different question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just using `as`:

```
->select('cities.name as city_name', 'provinces.name as province_name', 'countries.name as country_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try with this :

```
$city = DB::table('cities')
    ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
    ->join('countries', 'provinces.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
    ->get(['cities.name', 'provinces.name', 'countries.name']);
```

I hope it helps you !

Comment: No, it is not working. it is replacing all the values with the value of Country Name.

Comment: Try without the select clause !

Answer (score 0):

ok this is going to be a specific answer
learn about realtions in laravel and look at these

```
class example1 extends Model
    {
      public function examplefunction() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\othermodel', 'id');
    }
}
```

then use this query

```
$abc=example1::with('examplefunction')->get();
```

and there you go just take a look at a laravel relationship by using  this u  can get combined result

Answer (score -2):

```
 $products = User::select('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name','country_code','mobile')->get()->toArray();
       $gaurang = Ticket_Thread::select('body','title','resolv_note')
```